# extract, print and use a specific string from file line as a variable

Tags: regex, ruby

I am working with log files on which I want to check if parameters were set correctly. So I want to extract specific lines which contain the word "lineid".

```
 File.foreach("path/of/logfile.log").each do |line|
   puts line if line.match?('lineid')
 end
```

as expected I am getting back the following:

```
2019-08-07 15:21:09.783             'lineid' -> 'EBN.TXW.NBGNE00111'
```

Now I want to extract only the value "EBN.TXW.NBGNE00111" and store it in a variable. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe `puts line[/'lineid' -> '([^']+)'/, 1] if line.include? "lineid"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes thanks this only prints out the value of the line id. Do you also know how I now could store this in a variable? Thank you

Comment: You can use the assignment operator to assign a value to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, use a group regex to capture the line id.

```rb
 File.foreach("path/of/logfile.log").each do |line|
   if matches = line.match(/lineid.*?->\s*'(?<lineid>.*?)'/) 
     lineid = matches[:lineid]
     puts lineid
   end
 end
```